Jetpack Glance preview rendering problem, Failed to instantiate Composition Local
I'm following official docs to create a simple Jetpack Glance widget. I tried previewing the UI but I'm failing to do so. A portion of my code:
package io.github.yamin8000.owl.ui.content.widget

import android.content.Context
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.glance.GlanceId
import androidx.glance.GlanceTheme
import androidx.glance.appwidget.GlanceAppWidget
import androidx.glance.appwidget.provideContent
import androidx.glance.text.Text

internal class Widget : GlanceAppWidget() {
    override suspend fun provideGlance(context: Context, id: GlanceId) {
        provideContent {
            GlanceTheme {
                WidgetContent()
            }
        }
    }

    @Preview
    @Composable
    fun WidgetContent() {
        Text("Some Text!")
    }
}

Failed to instantiate Composition Local
This preview was unable to find a CompositionLocal. You might need to define it so it can render correctly.
And this is the stack trace I'm receiving: (Widget.kt:45 is Text("Some Text!"))
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid applier
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposablesKt.invalidApplier(Composables.kt:472)
    at androidx.glance.text.TextKt.Text(Text.kt:81)
    at io.github.yamin8000.owl.ui.content.widget.Widget.WidgetContent(Widget.kt:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposableInvoker.invokeComposableMethod(ComposableInvoker.jvm.kt:181)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposableInvoker.invokeComposable(ComposableInvoker.jvm.kt:226)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:504)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:502)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:539)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:497)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.InspectableKt.Inspectable(Inspectable.android.kt:61)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:444)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:443)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:438)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.access$WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:124)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:497)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.android.kt:494)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:428)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:252)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:251)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:186)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:119)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:118)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:110)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$2.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:139)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$2.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:138)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:248)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:138)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:123)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:90)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3302)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3235)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:725)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:1071)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeInitial(Composition.kt:633)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:619)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:123)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:114)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1289)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:114)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:164)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.jvm.kt:320)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.jvm.kt:198)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:121)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:114)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1364)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:21980)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3490)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:44)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:372)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:454)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:120)
    at com.android.tools.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:775)
    at com.android.tools.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:923)
    at com.android.tools.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:202)
    at com.android.tools.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:316)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)


This is my current enviroment
Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-233.14808.21.2331.11842104, built on May 15, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+0--11572160 amd64

Some questions like this suggest adding androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling library which is irrelevant for me because it's already added and other previews outside of Glance are working just fine.

You can see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/78613211/23865791
As wrote previously, Glance previews are now supported with the latest versions of Android Studio.
You need to use Glance 1.1.0-rc01 or newer :
implementation("androidx.glance:glance:1.1.1")
implementation("androidx.glance:glance-preview:1.1.1")
implementation("androidx.glance:glance-appwidget-preview:1.1.1")
implementation("androidx.glance:glance-appwidget:1.1.1")

And add the annotations with a size for your widget preview:
@OptIn(ExperimentalGlancePreviewApi::class)
@androidx.glance.preview.Preview(widthDp = 250, heightDp = 250)
@Composable
private fun Preview() {
...
}

But for the moment the Glance previews are limited compared to Compose previews.

For Glance, you need to use this dependency:
implementation "com.google.android.glance.tools:appwidget-host:"
And basically, you wrap your code in GlanceAppWidgetHostPreview like this:
@OptIn(ExperimentalGlanceRemoteViewsApi::class)
@Preview
@Composable
fun MyGlanceWidgetPreview() {
    // The size of the widget
    val displaySize = DpSize(200.dp, 200.dp)
    // Your GlanceAppWidget instance
    val instance = SampleGlanceWidget
    // Provide a state depending on the GlanceAppWidget state definition
    val state = preferencesOf(SampleGlanceWidget.countKey to 2)

    GlanceAppWidgetHostPreview(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        glanceAppWidget = instance,
        state = state,
        displaySize = displaySize,
    )
}

"Note: while the preview will render in Android Studio, the RemoteViews won't. You must always deploy them in a device."
This code and info are quoted from Google's glance-experimental-tools on Github.

Glance now supports previews within Android studio. See this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/78642757/3820290

Glance has its own Preview annotation, located in a different package from compose.
Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2 now supports glance previews.
See the steps to add the preview dependency and annotation here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#glance-widget-preview

The link doesn't work anymore/ doesn't refer to the correct article. Please add the steps to your answer.

Sounds like it moved to past releases page. https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/past-releases/as-koala-feature-drop-release-notes#glance-widget-preview

The official samples also contain examples https://github.com/android/platform-samples/tree/main/samples/user-interface/appwidgets/src/main/java/com/example/platform/ui/appwidgets/glance/layout
